# Applescript open URL and refresh every 5 seconds WITHOUT opening new tab

Tags: google-chrome, applescript, refresh

This is what I have so far but my problem is it opens the url in a new tab after every 5 seconds.

```
repeat
    delay 5
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        open location "https://www.google.com"
    end tell
end repeat
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `reload` command in the Chromium Suite.

Example:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    open location "https://www.google.com"
    repeat
        delay 5
        tell tab 1 of window 1 to reload
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me...

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell window 1
        tell tab 1
            set URL to "https://google.com/"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

You can also use `tell active tab` and `tell front window`.