# How to open a tab 2 on Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge if it doesn't exist?

Tags: applescript

I am new to AppleScript and tried an AppleScript solution to [open up a tab and load a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341061/applescript-open-url-and-refresh-every-5-seconds-without-opening-new-tab):

```
tell application "Google Chrome"   -- or "Microsoft Edge"
    tell window 1
        tell tab 2
            set URL to "https://google.com/"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

But if tab 2 doesn't exist, it won't do anything.

I then tried to solve it by [checking whether an URL exist in any tab](https://superuser.com/a/624551/1300955):

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with w in windows
        set i to 1
        repeat with t in tabs of w
            if URL of t starts with "https://mail.google" then
                set active tab index of w to i
                set index of w to 1
                return
            end if
            set i to i + 1
        end repeat
    end repeat
    open location "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox"
end tell
```

But it is sort of an overkill, and it opens up a new tab, rather than opening up a tab 2.

I then tried

```
tell application "Google Chrome"   -- or "Microsoft Edge"
    tell window 1
        open tab 2     -- added this line
        tell tab 2
            set URL to "https://google.com/"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

but no matter it is `open tab 2` or `activate tab 2` or `start tab 2`, it wouldn't work.  How can we make it work and, in general, how to find out the vocabularies or verbs that we can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open tab 2` is the problem. If a browser *window* exists and you want to create a new *tab* and set its **URL**, then:

```applescript
tell application "Google Chrome" to ¬
    if exists front window then ¬
        make new tab at end of ¬
            tabs of front window ¬
            with properties ¬
            {URL:"https://www.example.com"}
```

If a browser *window* exists and you want to change the **URL** of `tab 2`, then:

```applescript
tell application "Google Chrome" to ¬
    if exists front window then ¬
        tell front window to ¬
            if (exists tab 2) then ¬
                tell its tab 2 to ¬
                    set its URL to ¬
                        "https://www.example.com"
```

---

**Notes:**

- The *example* **AppleScript** *code* works with **Microsoft Edge** too.
- These examples can be expanded into normal *block* format using `if` *statements* to determine if **Google Chrome** and or **Microsoft Edge** exists, or are already running, and if running whether or not a *window* exists, etc. You just need to *code* it according to your needs/wants.
- Have a look at [AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH208-SW1)
- In **Script Editor** have a look at the **Library** for the **AppleScript** dictionary of any *application* you want to write *code* for. From the **Window** menu... **Library     ⇧⌘L**

---

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* below shows an example of coding for the existence of either **Google Chrome** or **Microsoft Edge** and whether or not they are running when you can then write *code* based on the conditions.  As written it favors **Google Chrome** but if it does exist then **Microsoft Edge** runs its *code*. To favor **Microsoft Edge** change the primary `if` *statement* structure to accommodate.

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    set existsGoogleChrome to exists file "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"
    set existsMicrosoftEdge to exists file "/Applications/Microsoft Edge.app"
end tell

if existsGoogleChrome then
    if running of application "Google Chrome" then
        tell application "Google Chrome"
            # Do Something
        end tell
    else
        tell application "Google Chrome"
            # Do Something Else
        end tell
    end if
else
    if existsMicrosoftEdge then
        if running of application "Microsoft Edge" then
            tell application "Microsoft Edge"
                # Do Something
            end tell
        else
            tell application "Microsoft Edge"
                # Do Something Else
            end tell
        end if
    end if
end if
```